# increment values in power apps

Tags: variables, powerapps

I want to increment the value of x in the code from 1 to the maximum value of the column `PageNo` present in the collection `coords`, here is the code:

```
ClearCollect(
  SVGCollection,
  {
    SVG: 
      Concat(
        ForAll(
          Filter(Coords, PageNo)
        ),
        EncodeUrl("<svg height='100%' 
          width='100%' 
          viewBox='2 400 2000 180 xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>" 
          & "<text x='" 
          & Left 
          & "' y='" 
          & Top 
          & "' font-family='Arial' font-size='16' fill='black'>" 
          & Text 
          & "</text>" 
          & "</svg>"
        )
      ),
      Value
    )
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

So the desired end result is a concatenated list of SVGs.

Get rid of ForAll() as it doesn't work in a non-behaviour property. Instead you could use the AddColumns() function:  `Concat(AddColumns(Coords,"SVGcolumn",EncodeUrl("<svg...")),SVGcolumn)`

Here's a helpful link on the [difference between Behaviour and non-Behaviour formulas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/working-with-formulas-in-depth) in PowerApps.

Also, if you want a single SVG with with elements for each page, you should structure your code in a way that the results of the Concat() formula are wrapped in the opening and closing  tags.

Comment: i want the code to iterate through a collection coords and create an svg plot with respect to the page number value given. in the above code if i put 1, itll concatenate all the words on page 1, then 2 and so on , but i do not want to manually enter the values and not providing an = will result in it taking values of all of the pages and plotting them on one svg, specifying pageno allows me to create an svg where a uri link is created of that specific page

Comment: sorry i had uploaded an incomplete code

Comment: refined my answer. you should definitely replace ForAll() with AddColumns() in this context.